# Paste gives "Object required" error

Tags: database, vba

I get this error:

> Error 424: Object required

on this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 1))
```

in the code below. Why?

```
    Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim erow
    Dim Filepath As String
    Filepath = "C:\Users\Julio Jesus Sanchez\Desktop\MRSK TXT\"
    MyFile = Dir("C:\Users\Julio Jesus Sanchez\Desktop\MRSK TXT\")

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "MRSK DATABASE.xlsm" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
    Range("A1:K1").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 1))

    MyFile = Dir

    Loop

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you think there's a mistake?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, it says that it is a '424' error and that an object is required

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: Help us help you.  How can we possibly answer this with so little info?  We're here to help (hopefully), not solve puzzles.

Comment: ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 1))

Comment: @roryap: I don't mind solving puzzles; it's the mind-reading that really kills me.

Answer (score 2):

You close the `ActiveWorkbook` and then refer to `ActiveSheet`, which `ActiveSheet` do you mean? If it is the master book you refer to then you should explicitly tell it that by setting it as an object, also is your VBA in a MS Access module or in Excel? You just tagged this as `Database` and `VBA`, I guess Excel as you don't have any reference to the Excel object.

```
Dim sh as Worksheet

Set sh = Workbooks("NameOfWorkBook.xlsx").WorkSheets("WorksheetName")
```

Then whenever you refer to the sheet:

```
sh.Paste Destination:=sh.Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 1))
```